# How to add list of songs with sections to UITableView using Swift?

Tags: ios, swift

I'm trying to create a simple music player that lists all the songs on my device in a `UITableView` split into alphabetic sections (like the **Apple Music Player**).

There are two areas I can't figure out:

1. Getting the number of songs per section so that I can create the
   correct number of rows in my table for each section
2. Accessing the items in each section to populate the section cells

My code is already pretty long so I'll put the pertinent info here:

I get the list of songs like this:

```
let songsQry:MPMediaQuery = MPMediaQuery.songsQuery()
```

This is where I'm unsure:

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    //How can I get the number of songs per Section to return??
    // this does not work:
    return songsQry.itemSections![0].count
}

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell:UITableViewCell = UITableViewCell(style: UITableViewCellStyle.Subtitle, reuseIdentifier: "cell")

//How do I get the song for the Section and Row??
    cell.textLabel?.text =  ????
    return cell
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm going to answer my own question.
I've posted similar questions here on SO and everyone replying said this couldn't be done and that additional Arrays were needed plus custom sort routines. That's simply not true.

Note however, that in my example code I show how get the same kind of results for an Album Query. The code for an Artist query is almost identical.

This code uses the return from an Album Query to:
1) Build a TableView index
2) Add Albums by Title (using Apple's sorting) to table Sections
3) Start playing an album when selected

Here's the Swift code to prove it:

```
// Set up a basic Albums query
let qryAlbums = MPMediaQuery.albumsQuery()
qryAlbums.groupingType = MPMediaGrouping.Album

// This chunk handles the TableView Index
    //create index title
    func sectionIndexTitlesForTableView(tableView: UITableView) -> [String]? {
        let sectionIndexTitles = qryAlbums.itemSections!.map { $0.title }
        return sectionIndexTitles
    }

    func tableView(tableView: UITableView, sectionForSectionIndexTitle title: String, atIndex index: Int) -> Int {
        return index
    }

// This chunk sets up the table Sections and Headers
    //tableview
    func tableView(tableView: UITableView, titleForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> String? {
        return (qryAlbums.itemSections![section].title)
    }

    func numberOfSectionsInTableView(tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
        return (qryAlbums.itemSections?.count)!
    }

// Get the number of rows per Section - YES SECTIONS EXIST WITHIN QUERIES
    func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {        
        return qryAlbums.collectionSections![section].range.length
    }

// Set the cell in the table
    func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell:UITableViewCell = UITableViewCell(style: UITableViewCellStyle.Subtitle, reuseIdentifier: "cell")

    // i'm only posting the pertinent Album code here.
    // you'll need to set the cell details yourself.

        let currLoc = qryAlbums.collectionSections![indexPath.section].range.location
        let rowItem = qryAlbums.collections![indexPath.row + currLoc]
        //Main text is Album name
        cell.textLabel!.text = rowItem.items[0].albumTitle
        // Detail text is Album artist
        cell.detailTextLabel!.text = rowItem.items[0].albumArtist!
        // Or number of songs from the current album if you prefer
        //cell.detailTextLabel!.text = String(rowItem.items.count) + " songs"

        // Add the album artwork
        var artWork = rowItem.representativeItem?.artwork        
        let tableImageSize = CGSize(width: 10, height: 10) //doesn't matter - gets resized below
        let cellImg: UIImageView = UIImageView(frame: CGRectMake(0, 5, myRowHeight-10, myRowHeight-10))
        cellImg.image = artWork?.imageWithSize(tableImageSize)
        cell.addSubview(cellImg)

        return cell
    }

// When a user selects a table row, start playing the album
// This assumes the myMP has been properly declared as a MediaPlayer
// elsewhere in code !!!

    func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
        let currLoc = qryAlbums.collectionSections![indexPath.section].range.location
        myMP.setQueueWithItemCollection(qryAlbums.collections![indexPath.row + currLoc])
        myMP.play()
    }
```

Also, here's a few helpful notes:

1) List all the Albums from the query:

```
for album in allCollections!{
    print("---------------")
    print("albumTitle \(album.items[0].albumTitle)")
    print("albumTitle \(album.representativeItem?.albumTitle)")
    print("albumTitle \(album.representativeItem?.valueForProperty(MPMediaItemPropertyAlbumTitle))")
} // each print statement is another way to get the title
```

2) Print out part of the query to see how it's constructed:

```
print("xxxx \(qryAlbums.collectionSections)")
```

I hope this helps some of you - if so up vote!

Answer (score 1):

The idea is simple:

> You need to create a sorted array **GroupedSongs** which holds objects
>   of type `[String: [MPMediaItem]]` (**key** is the **character** and
>   the **array** holds the **songs** corresponding that character). The
>   `[MPMediaItem]` array must be sorted from the title property.

Setting up the Table View Datasource

1. For each key we need a section which now is the main array
2. For each item we need a number a songs, so this will be the number
   of rows for our tableView

### Implementation

Code has comments so no more talking :D

```
var items: [[String: [MPMediaItem]]] = []

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

    items = loadSongsDividedByTitle()
}

// MARK: - Delegation

// MARK: Table view datasource

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    let object: [String: [MPMediaItem]] = items[section]
    let key = Array(object.keys)[0] // We always have one object there
    let songs: [MPMediaItem] = object[key]!

    return songs.count
}

func numberOfSectionsInTableView(tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
    return items.count
}

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell:UITableViewCell = UITableViewCell(style: UITableViewCellStyle.Subtitle, reuseIdentifier: "cell")

    // Load song from the array
    let object: [String: [MPMediaItem]] = items[indexPath.section]
    let key = Array(object.keys)[0] // We always have one object there
    let songs: [MPMediaItem] = object[key]!
    let song = songs[indexPath.row]

    // Bind title of the song to the cell text label
    cell.textLabel?.text = song.title

    return cell
}

// MARK: - Helpers

func loadSongsDividedByTitle() -> [[String: [MPMediaItem]]] {
    guard var songs = MPMediaQuery.songsQuery().items else { return [] }

    // Sort songs
    songs = songs.sort({$0.title < $1.title})

    // Create a new dictionary to hold array of words for each letter
    var object: [String: [MPMediaItem]] = [:]

    // Songs holding a dictionary with music
    var groupedSongs : [[String: [MPMediaItem]]] = []

    // Enumerate in words
    for mediaItem in songs {
        guard let title: String = mediaItem.title! else { continue } // If we don't have the title skip the song

        // Use the first character as a key for each array
        let key = String(title.characters.first!)

        if var songGroup = object[key] {
            // If we have an array, then append the new word there
            songGroup.append(mediaItem)
            object[key] = songGroup
        } else {
            // Create an array for that key
            object[key] = [mediaItem]
        }
    }

    // Add every object into one big array
    for (key, value) in object {
        let sortedSongs = value.sort({$0.title < $1.title})
        groupedSongs.append([key: sortedSongs])
    }

    // Sort it alphabetically from a-z
    groupedSongs = groupedSongs.sort({Array($0.keys)[0] < Array($1.keys)[0]})

    return groupedSongs
}
```

### Playground output with strings

[image]

Comment: I tried your suggested code but am getting an error:  "Missing argument for parameter #1 in call"  for this statement: var items = loadSongsDividedByTitle()

Comment: @wayneh Yeah that is because you are calling that not inside a scope of a function. I was just telling you how to call it, but not the place where, that because I was assuming that you know how to declare variables in Swift. Anyway you have my answer updated :)

Comment: @wayneh did you try it?

Comment: yes, I did. There are two issues - 1) The sorting is not like the Apple OS sorting where, for example, item beginning with "The" are sorted by the second word and items beginning with "(" ignore the parenthesis. 2) Using the first char of a word for index gives index items that are excessive - like "(" and "4" end every other character that is not A-Z.

Comment: Then you need to create your own sorting algorithm to sort songs. I am using the default one, so try some and stuff and then go and ask another question on SO if you have trouble to find that, as this is out of context in this case. You asked to **split into alphabetic sections** (which I answered and provided code) not creating a sorting algorithm

Comment: Actually, I asked "split into alphabetic sections (like the Apple Music Player)" which is not addressed by your response. I've asked another question anyway.

Comment: @wayneh It is not good to change your question by adding extra requirements, where you mention 2 areas where you have trouble. You are a programmer and you understand the difference between a normal sort, and putting other requirements. You should at least know how the Apple's algorithm works, and that makes this question totally another matter. You could make your own algorithm here for sorting and this answer works totally great.